# Can't create my database using ssh php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hey guys I'm having a little trouble getting my database to actually create.

my professor provided us with a .data file containing all of the queries that need to run to create the tables and insert the data into them.  I run the following line of code:

```
mysql -u user -p pass >use dbname.data
```

but then when I try to query the database or do anything to it it tells me that there aren't any tables in the database.  I have also tried the following with no luck:

```
mysql -u user -p pass >create dbname.data
mysql -u user -p pass >create database dbname.data
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction here?  I'm running out of time and my professor is literally no help!

thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I ran the following and it ran a bunch of queries saying "Query ok, 1 row affected"

```
use databasename;
source dbfilename.data
```

but now when I run these:

```
use databasename;
show tables;
```

it says "empty set"

Answer (score 1):

Try this

mysql -u user -p pass dbname < file.data

Answer (score 0):

Check the .data file if there's any 'USE databasename' query and if the database name is the same as the one you expect.